# Boost with Qt Creator and Linux

Tags: linux, boost, qt-creator

So I added:

```
LIBS += 
       -lboost_system\                                                         
       -lboost_gregorian
```

To my projects .pro, but in Creator it says "cannot find -lboost_system".  I tried using "UNCLUDEPATH" but that broke the path for all libraries.

Anyone have any ideas how to use boost::gregorian with Qt Creator?

EDIT:  Below works to get it recognized, but breaks all other libraries.

INCLUDEPATH +=     /usr/include
LIBS += -L"/usr/include/boost" -lboost_system -lboost_gregorian

Comment: What do you mean it broke path for all other libraries?

Answer (score 12):

I just tried by myself and it is working and it is my first Qt and boost program.

In the .pro file you only need to add

```
LIBS += \
       -lboost_system\
```

I did not mention include file as I am using mentioning boost dir in my include in source file.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
```

For packages, if you are using Fedora/RHEL system just do

```
yum install boost boost-devel
```

And for Ubuntu based system

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Typo fix (Ubuntu case): sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Answer (score 3):

LIBS should not include /usr/include/boost and INCLUDEPATH includes /usr/include by default.

Make sure you have **libboost-system-dev** (or devel, depends on your distribution) package installed.