# Link Boost in Qt Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, boost

I want to link boost in my pro file and found following answer:

[Boost with Qt Creator and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480765/boost-with-qt-creator-and-linux)

I build a minimal example:

My pro File

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = threadtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH +=/path/boost/
LIBS += -L/path/boost/lib/ -lboost_thread -lboost_system

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

My main:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

void woker(){
    boost::posix_time::seconds t(10);
    std::cout <<" working" << std::endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(t);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout <<" r" << std::endl;

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    boost::thread w(woker);
    w.join();
    std::cout <<" d" << std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I get the undefined reference to boost error. I don't understand this...

In Windows I only did:

```
LIBS += "-LC:/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-10.0/"
```

However, this is also not working in Linux.

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Edit

```
14:41:04: Führe Build-Schritte für Projekt threadtest aus...
14:41:04: Starte "/usr/bin/qmake-qt4" /home/user/threadtest/threadtest.pro -r -spec linux-g++
14:41:04: Der Prozess "/usr/bin/qmake-qt4" wurde normal beendet.
14:41:04: Starte "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/home/user/threadtest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_Pfad__System__Release'
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../threadtest -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I../boost -I. -I../threadtest -I. -o main.o ../threadtest/main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o threadtest main.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/home/user/boost/lib/ -lQtCore -lpthread 
main.o: In function `woker()':
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/threadtest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_Pfad__System__Release'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2aa): undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::ptime const&)'
main.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::~thread_data()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEED2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEED5Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
main.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::~thread_data()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEED0Ev[_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEED5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
main.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>* boost::detail::heap_new_impl<boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>, void (*&)()>(void (*&)())':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail13heap_new_implINS0_11thread_dataIPFvvEEERS4_EEPT_T0_[boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>* boost::detail::heap_new_impl<boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>, void (*&)()>(void (*&)())]+0x52): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x60): undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6a): undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x92): undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc6): undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
main.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEEE[typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [threadtest] Error 1
14:41:06: Der Prozess "/usr/bin/make" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen des Projekts threadtest(Ziel: Desktop)
Bei der Ausführung von Build-Schritt 'Make'
```

---

EDIT 2:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(app_project)

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT path/boost)
find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread filesystem)
if(BOOST_FOUND)
  message("boost found")
endif()
add_executable(test main.cpp)

if(TARGET test)
  target_link_libraries(test
    -lboost_thread
    -lboost_system
)
endif()
```

I wrote a small example with cmake. This is running well, however on cmake i have the command ignore boost system path. You know something similar to qt ?

Comment: Show us the error and the full command line being run to compile and link.

Comment: I add the output as edit. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have the correct names for the boost libraries?  In my version of Linux, the libraries where "libboost_thread-mt" and "libboost_system-mt".  In windows my boost libraries have -vc90-mt-1_55 appended to them.

Comment: my names are libboost_thread.a and libboost_system.a so it should be correct. I forgot to tell you that i build this libs on my own so it is the newest bosot version 1.55. Could that be the problem that he find the new and the old one of the system?

Answer (score 2):

For VS2008, Boost 1_55, Qt4 4.8.6, I was able to get your code to compile with the following qmake file.

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = threadtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app
win32{
INCLUDEPATH += d:/gnu/vs2008/x64/include
LIBS += -Ld:/gnu/vs2008/x64/lib 
LIBS += -lboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_55
LIBS += -lboost_system-vc90-mt-1_55

}
unix{
LIBS += -L/usr/lib64
LIBS += -L/usr/local -L/usr -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt
}

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

With the same qmake pro file, i was also able to get your code to compile on RHEL6 with Qt4 4.8.6 and the stock Boost

Comment: i think this is my problem, I don't use the stock boost. Can i tell qt to ignore the stock boost?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried using only `INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/boost/directory/` worked on both Windows and Linux. No need to use `LIBS += ....` .

Comment: do you use boost threads and this example ? Do you have stock boost on linux? Because when you use boost thread you have to link the libraries. I think in your case qt automatic link boost thread to your stock boost

Comment: I think adding it to include path, includes the libraries automatically or something. Atleast that's what I think because I don't have stock boost on my linux. I was using the boost graph. Haven't used boost thread. Don't know why its working. Maybe I will have a look at it again and will be able to tell you better.