# linux : make boost work with Qt Creator (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, linux, boost, qt-creator

I've been trying to make boost work with my current IDE : Qt Creator. I've done everything that's written in this topic : [Boost with Qt Creator and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480765/boost-with-qt-creator-and-linux) and many others, but I still have this error :

> /usr/include/boost/test/unit_test_suite.hpp:228: erreur : undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite()'

and many others that follow

my base code is this one :

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
    BOOST_CHECK( true );
}
```

which I got from this small tutorial : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html

My .pro looks like this :

```
QT += testlib
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

OTHER_FILES += \
    ...

SOURCES += \
    ...

HEADERS += \
    ...

LIBS += \
   -lboost_system
```

with files instead of "..."

I've done the

> sudo apt-get libboost-all-dev

For information, I'm using Qt Creator 3.6.0 and Qt 5.5.1 on kubuntu 14.04 LTS

What should I do ? I hope to find an answer

Thanks in advance and tell me if I forgot to mention something

Comment: Adding `-lboost_system` solved the linked question, because the asker needed that library in particular, it's not a general solution. I don't know the exact name atm, but you need the library that contains Boost.Test.

Comment: [`-lboost_unit_test_framework`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libboost-test1.54-dev/filelist).

Comment: Yep it worked, thank you

Comment: @cv_and_he can you convert the comment to an answer ?
I'll also change the question a little bit so that it expresses more clearly the concern
Thanks again :-D

Comment: If you understand the problem, feel free to make your own answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Boost 1.41 is ancient, that tutorial is probably outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @cv_and_me for the answer :

The error was that I was not including the good library.

> LIBS += \
>
> -lboost_system

should be replaced by

> LIBS += \
>
> -lboost_unit_test_framework

I made the error to belive that boost was only for unit testing, but it could do a lot more, so we have to add the right part of boost that we will be using (in my case, the unit testing framework).

(for people at the same stage than this post, I then used this tutorial for making a good project structure, separating unit tests and the app : http://dragly.org/2014/03/13/new-project-structure-for-projects-in-qt-creator-with-unit-tests/)